# Reason of making properties immutable in react-leaflet v3

Tags: react-leaflet

What was the reason of making properties in react-leaflet v3 immutable per default? Now if I change any of such a property then I must use different `key` to force component update. Anyway, is this the correct approach?

In v2 I found it better that properties were per default mutable and I didn't have to do such "hacks". (Property) mutability is one of the core concepts of React.